Notebook CPU upgrade: Pentium to i7
I have an old notebook and I'm considering to upgrade the CPU. My current setup is:

Product Name: Notebook Gateway NE56R
Motherboard: Q5WVH LA-7912P, rev 1.0
Chipset: Mobile Intel® HM77 Express | specs
CPU: Intel Pentium 2020M (TDP 35W, FCPGA988) | specs

Below TDP 45W, the Intel site states that the HM77 chipset supports even an i7:

Intel Core i7-3610QM (TDP 45W, FCPGA988) | specs
Intel Core i7-3612QM (TDP 35W, FCPGA988) | specs

Source: Mobile Intel® HM77 Express Chipset | Compatible Products
Unfortunately, I don't have much info about what cpus the mobo + bios supports.
Question

Can I upgrade my system to an i7-3610QM or i7-3612QM? Is it safe?
Any heat dissipation issues to worry?


Pentium 2020M: 2C/2T, TDP 35W  |  i7-3612QM: 4C/8T, TDP 35W. Therefore, there should be a considerable performance improvement without much TDP change.

Is it possible to do? Yes... but you'd have to revise power, cooling and PCB. Could you put a Ferrari engine in a Renault Dauphine? Sure. To what purpose??

@Ramhound Acer V3-571G cpu upgrade | At least according to this forum, the i7-3630QM is indeed supported by my notebook. However, it would be nice to have an official source confirming that.

While it is possible the chipset and mainboard support this upgraded chip, unless the laptop is designed to handle the increased thermal load the chip will, in the best case, throttle itself below your expectations, or in the worst case, bake itself and the surrounding components.
I am entirely ignoring:

Whether the chip is soldered to the mainboard (on most laptops it is).
Whether the mainboard and firmware support the upgraded chip.

While I am ignoring these, you should not. Open your computer and see whether the chip is user serviceable before proceeding.
Focusing only on the thermal aspects, you should search to see whether this laptop offered a version with the upgraded chip. If it did not, you should not install it yourself.
If this laptop model DOES offer a version with this upgraded chip find service documents for this computer, specifically diagrams of the internal designs and parts. You will need to use these to confirm whether the cooling system is any different between your own model and the model with the upgraded chip. The cooling system will involve the cooling ports, the design and model numbers of the fans, the heat pipes, the heat sinks, and the power supply. If the cooling system is different in any way, you should not install the upgraded chip.
If the cooling system appears to be exactly the same, then you might have a chance of a) successfully upgrading the system, and b) actually deriving a benefit from it.

I'm 100% sure the CPU is not soldered to the mainboard.


"unless the laptop is designed to handle the increased thermal load" Both Pentium 2020M (my current CPU) and i7-3612QM have the same TDP of 35W.

